# Choose the closest k points from given n points

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry, computational-geometry

You are given a set U of n points on the plane and you can compute distance between any pair of points in constant time. Choose a subset of U called C such that C has exactly k points in it and the distance between the farthest 2 points in C is as small as possible for given k. 1 < k <= n

What's the fastest way to do this besides the obvious n-choose-k solution?

Comment: I have a feeling this problem is NP-complete, a sketch of a reduction from a known NP-complete problem would suffice too :)

Comment: Done - accepted an answer (although its only a link to a journal paper)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution is shown in [Finding k points with minimum diameter and related problems](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WH3-4CRJ34X-W&_user=10&_coverDate=03/31/1991&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=dbd17c453a3361fe6c94c41b64e39b21&searchtype=a) - Aggarwal, 1991.
The algorithm described therein has running time: `O(k^2.5 n log k  +  n log n)`

For those who have no access to the paper:
the problem is called *k-diameter* and definied as

> Find a set of *k* points with minimum diameter. The *diameter* of a set is the maximum distance between any points of the set.

I cannot really give an *overview* over the presented algorithm, but it includes computing the *(3k - 3)th order Voronoi diagram* of the points, and then solve the problem for each of the *O(kn)* Voronoi sets (by computing maximum independent sets in some bipartite graphs)... I guess that I am trying to say is, that it is highly non-trivial, and far beyond both an interview and this site :-)

Comment: This is good if by "diameter", Aggarwal means the largest distance between the k points.  If Aggarwal means the diameter of the smallest enclosing circle, then it's a different problem.  I'm not going to pay $31 to find out :)  Maybe someone could post a simplified poly-time version of his solution?

Answer (score 9):

Since this is an interview question, here is my shot at a solution.  *(As dcn points out below, this is not guaranteed to return the optimal solution, though it should still be a decent heuristic.  Good catch, dcn!)*

1. Create a set S<sub>p</sub> with a single point P.
2. Compute the distance between every point in S<sub>p</sub> and every point outside of it, then add the point with the smallest max distance to S<sub>p</sub>.
3. Repeat 2. until S<sub>p</sub> has k points.
4. Repeat 1-3 using each point once as the initial P.  Take the S<sub>p</sub> which has the smallest max distance.

There are O(k) points in S<sub>p</sub>, and O(n) points outside of it, so finding the point with the smallest max distance is O(nk).  We repeat this k times, then repeat the *whole* procedure n times, for an overall complexity of **O(n<sup>2</sup>k<sup>2</sup>)**.

We can improve on this by caching the max distance between *any* point in S<sub>p</sub> and each point outside of S<sub>p</sub>.  If `maxDistanceFromPointInS[pointOutsideS]` is, say, an O(1) hash-table containing the current max distance between every point `pointOutsideS` and some point inside S<sub>p</sub>, then every time we add a new point `newPoint`, we set `maxDistanceFromPointInS[p] = Max(maxDistanceFromPointInS[p], distance(newPoint, p))` for all points `p` outside of S<sub>p</sub>.  Then finding the smallest max distance is O(n), adding a point to S<sub>p</sub> is O(n).  Repeating this k times gives us O((n+n)k) = O(nk).  Finally, we repeat the *whole* procedure n times, for an overall complexity of **O(n<sup>2</sup>k)**.

We could improve finding the smallest max distance to O(1) using a heap, but that would not change the overall complexity.

---

By the way, it took an hour to write this all up - there's no way I could have done this in an interview.

Comment: Thank you for this pointer - this was not an interview question I have asked but was thinking about if I should ask or not to atleast see how they think.

Comment: @wrick: How would *you* answer this question?  I don't think it's fair to ask a question you yourself cannot answer..

Comment: @BlueRaja - that's why I asked it here hoping there might be a easy solution I was not thinking of. Now I have changed my mind and decided not to ask this :)

Comment: Your described solution implements some heuristic but does not give an optimal answer. Also I think the reference you gave is wrong, since it is about a different problem: smallest-k-enclosing circle it not the same as "distance between farthest points ... [minimal]" (consider the case for a equilateral triangle!)

Comment: @dcn: Do you have a counter-example?  Of course, [proof by lack of counter-example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514/conjectures-that-have-been-disproved-with-extremely-large-counterexamples/527#527) is not a proof, but I'm still not convinced it's *not* correct.  Also, the example of an equilateral triangle would be solved correctly by smallest k-enclosing circle..

Comment: Why smallest k-enclosing circle is different: consider a equilateral triangle with side length a. The smallest circle containing all 3 endpoints has radius r=3a/sqrt(a) > a/2. Now take three other points to be collinear with distance r-epsilon. They fit in a circle of radius r-epsilon (which is smaller than the circle form the triangle), however the max distance in the two cluster of three points is 2*(r-epsilon) vs a (for the triangle case)

Comment: Why your solution does not work: take a equilateral triangle with side length a. Now add three more points to the plain: one for each corner of the triangle, facing away from the triangle, and with distance b=a-epsilon to the triangle corner (similar to a star) . Your algorithm will for every initial P always *take an edge of length b* in the first iteration of Step 2. However the correct solution for k=3 is the middle triangle!

Comment: @dcn Damn, you are right on both counts.  I'll edit my answer - good catch!

Answer (score 1):

This is still a messy idea, <strike>I am not sure if it actually works</strike> It does not work. Leaving the wrong answer here for posterity.

```
For each point in U
    make a list of the distance to each point in U
    sort the list
    add largest distance to a max-heap.
while any of the lists have more than k elements
    remove max of heap twice
    remove corresponding elements from the two lists they came from
    add the two newly exposed largest elements from those two lists to the heap
Any of the lists left with k elements will list the elements in C
```

Basically, find the two points who currently look like they could both be in the subset together, and which have the largest pairwise distance, and then rule out their both being in the subset together. Repeat until you are left with only one possible way to form a k-sized subset.

This should be time complexity O((n^2)log(n)) and space complexity O(n^2).

Comment: Greedy algorithm won't work as you might end up selecting C={x,y1,y2} where x-y1 and x-y2 distances are small but y1 and y2 are far away from each other

Answer (score 0):

Its doable in [deterministic polynomial time](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQxQEwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fviewer%3Fa%3Dv%26q%3Dcache%3A5Bmq1RXbN5kJ%3Aciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%253Fdoi%253D10.1.1.132.407%2526rep%253Drep1%2526type%253Dpdf%2BComputing%2Bthe%2Bsmallest%2Bk-enclosing%2Bcircle%2Band%2Brelated%2Bproblems%2Bpdf%26hl%3Den%26gl%3Dus%26pid%3Dbl%26srcid%3DADGEESgsrIgSt754bQqz6YqN_ZwxB8p7kJZrN3zS7Yj5yssizGVm4ctA90_xBzkH2BpdxlLajmX-qWkiSXP4-qEqjzWqcZ7R_b3k92e9Atm2Yz0ZxFpQcaGdc4NQI2Gi1eX3gyodndT_%26sig%3DAHIEtbRJxkcrzlu1vrzakZUm2z8syMI1Hw&ei=GOOUTdrkM8iD0QHQsOD-Cw&usg=AFQjCNH6VnVgjphGU2d59_n_3sVeyon4fQ&sig2=DMZ-oIF702N_Y4QRgOg0Kw) apparently.

But I don't understand their algorithm. It seems the circles they choose are always one of the input points. Can someone shed some light on this or explain neatly what they do (just the section 2 would suffice)?

Comment: Look at my comment for the answer of @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft. The paper is about a different problem!

Comment: So the question "Find the smallest circle (radius and center) that encloses atleast k points from the given n points" and the question "Find the subset of k points from given n points such that maximum distance between 2 points in the chosen subset is minimzed" are different questions?

Comment: Yes, as shown by my counterexample. However, I found "your" problem referenced in the paper you linked above. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem that was asked seems difficult. If the points were not in the plane and had arbitrary distances, it would be NP-hard by reduction from k-clique (take an arbitrary unweighted graph, and add edges of length infinity for missing edges, and edges of length 1 for existing edges -- a clique of size k exists whenever the 'closest k points' have a maximum mutual distance of 1 rather than infinity). However, since the points are constrained to being in the plane so that such distance labelings are forbidden, it's possible that there may be a solution. At least, it seems amenable to close approximation.

If your interview meant 'smallest diameter circle enclosing k points', then the following might be the fastest correct algorithm you could reasonably come up with by yourself in an interview:

For each set of size 3, compute the smallest circle that contains these points, and check whether each point is contained in this circle. If the number contained is at least k, update the minimum diameter accordingly.

Essentially, this is a quadruply nested for loop, so the running time is O(n^4).

Comment: This will give a good approximation, but it's not exactly right.  For k=3, let's say you have three points each 1 unit apart from each other (diameter = 1.154...).  Someplace else there are 2 points 1.1 units apart, with a 3rd point in between (diameter = 1.1).  Your algorithm will incorrectly choose the latter group of three points.

Comment: According to my understanding, 1.1 is the correct return value for the this problem instance, so this is not a counterexample. *Edit: Oh ok, I see what you mean.

Answer (score -2):

This should be a good approximate solution if you don't have too many outliers

```
p = mean center (average x, y) of U
M = U sorted by distance to p
C = M[0:k]
```

Comment: Approximate solutions are never good enough. This one will fail for sure.

Comment: @Snowbear: I'd hate to be the person who had to teach you about NP-complete problems...

Comment: Approximate solutions are tricky traps as you have to prove their error bounds and run-times. You can ofcourse do other optimizations in real-life like find clusters etc