# Given a set U of n points in R^N, find a subset S of size 1<k<n of minimum diameter

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

It is the following question with the points instead of lying in a 2D plane, are located in a higher dimensional space: [Choose the closest k points from given n points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5492526).

What is known about the above problem? If it is NP-hard then what is the best approximation ratio known and any lower bounds?

Comment: In a high dimension space I would expect that the curse of dimensionality makes the naive algorithm best.  Also I would not expect to find `k` points very close to each other.

Comment: @btilly does it help if we know that all the n points can be confined inside a sphere of radius c/\sqrt{n} for some constant c? Also k=\sqrt{n}.