# Find nearest points - Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am faced with the problem to find the closest 100 points for each 1 000 000 points in an array. Points are 2D with x and y coordinates. What I have in mind is only the brute force way using the Euclidean distance, which even multithreaded will take way too long.

Right now I have a Point class that implements Runnable containing x and y. Coordinates could be nagative and positive numbers.

Can someone suggest or write an algorithm, or just give some ideas on how I can improve performance.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-graphs

Comment: [Choose the closest k points from given n points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492526/choose-the-closest-k-points-from-given-n-points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way i see it would be to do it through an adjacency matrix, that way, each element k would have to calculate n-k distances (as you can reuse previously computed distances from past elements).
you go from the brute force way of O(n<sup>n</sup>) to something somewhat lower though that would require the computer to store a 10<sup>6</sup>x10<sup>6</sup> matrix that you would need to quicksort or something afterward.

another way (which might be better) would be to calculate for each point their distance to [0,0], sort the array by this distance then for each point calculate the distance to the adjacent points in the array